# login PHP to Active Directory Fail

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to verify the authentication of a user through a simple PHP code but I always get the same error  "Invalid credentials ".

```
$ldap_dn = "uid=".$_POST["username"].",DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_con =   ldap_connect("xxx", 389);
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);

//check connection
if ($ldap_con === FALSE) {
    die("<p> Couldn't connect to LDAP service </p>");
    } else {
        echo "<p> connessione avvenuta con successo </p>";
}

// check authentication
if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password)){
    echo "Autenticato";
}else{
    echo "Autenticazione Fallita <br>";
    echo ldap_error($ldap_con);
}
```

PHP code runs on XAMP on a PC W7pro already logged into the company domain.

I have obtained the AD address from the same machine on which I perform the tests; for retrive DN I've used the program  "Softerra LDAP browser", but actually I'm not sure for this parameter.

When a user logs on to the domain, the username uses three letters of the surname followed by two of the name, e.g. Name = Alfred / Surname = Pecora username = pecal.

Comment: Try changing "uid" in your `$ldap_dn` to "CN". Also, does your domain really have that many domain/subdomains? I count 5 "DC=xxx" which seems like a lot. The other (easy) way would be to use the full userPrincipalName like someone else already suggested. `username@domain.tld`

Comment: @KamaranL I will try your suggestion (uid <->CN). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does $ldap_dn in your code match the DN in AD properly? 
If you are administrator for the AD, you can confirm it by executing dsquery command on DOS prompt on the AD.

e.g.,

```
dsquery user -name pecal
```

Or you can use the format <name>@<domain> instead of DN format:

```
$ldap_dn = $_POST["username"]."@example.com";
```

Comment: I'm not administrator for the AD and I'm not able to execute dsquery command; I use a client PC. Actually I'm not sure that  $ldap_dn matches the DN.. For my purposes I am obliged to use the format "pecal" (samaccountname)

Answer (score 0):

I ran a new test:

```
$adServer = "xxx";

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer,389);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$ldapRdnLogin = "CN=MyName MySurname,OU=CED,OU=Users,DC=intranet,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=it";
$ldapRdn = "OU=Users,DC=intranet,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=it";


ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldapRdnLogin, $password); 


if ($bind) {
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,$ldapRdn,$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
    {
        if($info['count'] > 1)
            break;
        echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($info);
        echo '</pre>';
        $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
    }
    @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    $msg = ldap_error($ldap);
    echo $msg;
}
```

In the above example the binding **"MyName MySurname"** \ **DN** works and I can perform the search.

I think that the problem is to find the right DN to bind with sAMAccountName